# C#からAccessを操作するとき、OLEDBをインストールしなくても動かす方法

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

お世話になります。

C#(4.5)を使用して、Accessのデータベースを操作するアプリを組んでいるのですが、
他のPCで使用するにはそれぞれのPCにAccessDatabaseEngineをインストールしないと
動かないとどこのサイト様でも書かれているのですが、これはどうしても必須なのでしょうか。

一台ごと、Officeのビット数を確認しながら上記のパッケージを入れなければならないのは
非常に重荷だと感じるのです。Excelなどのアドオンを思い出してしまいます。

もし、回避しても動かす方法があればお教えください。

或いは、.Netのように、新しいバージョンが必要なときはダイアログなどが出てインストールを
促すような方法でもあるならば、それでも良いかと思います。

なければないでソースでインストールするように促すので、できるかできないかをご助力
いただきたいと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

標準のJet4.0のOLEDBでは古いAccess(2003以下)のmdbしか扱えないので、事実上必須と思います。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。必須というならば仕方がないのですが、WebSurferさんもおっしゃっているように、Officeが入っていればすでに入っている状態ならば、そもそも必要のない気もするのですが…。

Comment: Officeが入ってる前提なら使用出来ますね。

Comment: [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDBについてまとめてみた] https://qiita.com/yaju/items/7b0aa9e9f30005f60388

Comment: ありがとうございます。ほっと安心できると思ったのですが、うちの社はほとんどがクイック形式のインストーラーで走っています。…こりゃ一台ごとセットアップしなければならない可能性が出てきてしましました…。

Comment: 前提条件が絶対Accessが入っているということなら、アプリ側をx86とx64版を用意しておいて、起動時にOfficeチェックしてインストールされている側のアーキテクチャで起動し直すとかすればいけそうな気がします。（多分）

Comment: ACE.OLEDBが入らないインストール方法をしているなら、もうDataBaseEngine入れるしかないですね…

Comment: ありがとうございます。依然教えていただいたヒット数の識別方法に追加してやってみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET を使って Access を操作するなら JET または ACE プロバイダは必須です。JET は OS 同梱なので扱うのが .mdb ファイルに限るなら JET を使ってはいかが？　アプリを x86 でコンパイルしておけば済むはずです。

Access 2007 以降の .accdb ファイルを扱うなら ACE をインストールするほか手はないと思います。その場合は 32/64-bit の煩わしさは避けられません。

（煩わしさとは、32-bit 版でないと Visual Studio のウィザードが使えない、32/64-bit 版は同じ PC に共存できない、Office をインストール済みのユーザーは ACE もインストールされている・・・など）

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。どうしても必須ということならば仕方ないですね。そこで一点、気になったのですが、Officeが入っていれば、すでにACEも入っている…ということですか？もしそういうことならば、わざわざインストしなくても済むということなのでしょうか…。それならば話は早いのですが…。

Comment: 普通に Office をインストールしていれば、ACE も一緒にインストールされているはずです（ただし、 Office には簡易インストールという方法があるそうで、その場合は ACE はインストールされませんが）。ただ、話は決して早くはないですよ。ユーザーは必ず Office をインストールしてあるという条件でも、32/64-bit の選択がユーザー任せになるので上の回答に述べた 32/64-bit の煩わしさは倍増すると思いますけど。

Comment: ありがとうございます。うちの社はその『簡易式』が大半(中にはプリインストールもいるとは思いますが)なので、こりゃどうしても煩わしさはついて回りそうです。何とかコード側でできないか試してみます。

Comment: ユーザーが ACE をインストールしてあると煩わしらさが倍増すると言いましたが、その意味を分かっておられるでしょうか？